# How to get whole command line when using bash autocompletion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Regarding defining a new bash autocompletion using `complete -F`, i.e. writing  a shell function to produce the autocompletion, the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion) says

> The shell function function is executed in the current shell environment. When it is executed, $1 is the name of the command whose arguments are being completed, $2 is the word being completed, and $3 is the word preceding the word being completed

But this is extremely little context!  Ideally I'd like the *whole* command line so far.  The current completion may well depend on options set much further back than the previous word.  Is it possible to access the whole command line in bash's autocompletion?

[In `zsh` the entire command line seems to be available in the `$words` variable, and the number of the argument over which the cursor lies is given by `$CURRENT`.  I'm wondering if there's something similar for `bash`, or some other way of accessing equivalent functionality.]

Answer (score 1):

`bash` provides the full list of arguments in the shell variable `$COMP_WORDS` and the index of the word under the cursor in `$COMP_CWORD`.  Other useful shell variables related to completion start with `$COMP...` and are listed in the "Shell Variables" section of `man bash` and in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables).